# There is an issue to connected Bluetooth in foregroud sevice android

Tags: java, android

in this code its works in the background but not working in the foreground I want to add a foreground service that implements Bluetooth connectivity and GATT connection as well. please help me in this code
in this code its works in the background but not working in the foreground I want to add a foreground service that implements Bluetooth connectivity and GATT connection as well. please help me in this code
in this code its works in the background but not working in the foreground I want to add a foreground service that implements Bluetooth connectivity and GATT connection as well. please help me in this code

```
public static BluetoothGattCharacteristic colorCharacteristic;
private HashMap<String, BluetoothGatt> gattHash = new HashMap<String, BluetoothGatt>();
private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private boolean isConnected;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    initAdapter();
    return kBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}


private String address;


public void initBluetoothDevice(final String address, final Context context) {

    
    this.address = address;
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if(isConnected())return;
    if(null!=mGatt){
        refreshDeviceCache(mGatt);
        mGatt=null;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, bleGattCallback,BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
    } else {
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, bleGattCallback);
    }
    if (mGatt == null) {
        System.out.println(device.getAddress() + "gatt is null");
    }

    // this.mContext=context;
    // reconnect(true);

}



public String getDeviceAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
                         final byte[] scanRecord) {
        if (device.getAddress().equals(address) && Math.abs(rssi) < 90) {
        });

        }
    }
};


private void initAdapter() {
    if (bluetoothManager == null) {
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (bluetoothManager == null) {
            return;
        }
    }
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}

    public void disconnect() {
    NeedReconnect = false;
    if (mGatt == null)
        return;
    mGatt.disconnect();
}


public void disconnect(String address) {
    ArrayList<BluetoothGatt> gatts = new ArrayList<BluetoothGatt>();
    for (BluetoothGatt gatt : arrayGatts) {

        if (gatt != null && gatt.getDevice().getAddress().equals(address)) {
            gatts.add(gatt);
            // gatt.disconnect();
            gatt.close();
            // gatt = null;
        }
    }
    arrayGatts.removeAll(gatts);

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BleService getService() {
        return BleService.this;
    }
}

private int discoverCount;

private Object ob = new Object();
private BluetoothGattCallback bleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                        int newState) {
        String action = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange:  status"+ status+" newstate "+newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            if (status == 133) {
                mGatt.close();
                mGatt = null;
                return;
            }
            action = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            try {
                gatt.discoverServices();
        
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            isConnected=false;
            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: "+ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
            if (mGatt != null) {
                mGatt.close();
                mGatt = null;
            }
            queues.clear();
            if(!NeedReconnect) {
                action = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(action);
            }

        }
    }

 
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        // if (mGatt == null)
        // return;
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            String address = gatt.getDevice().getAddress();
            String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
                    .getName();
            setCharacteristicNotification(true);
          /*  if (gatt != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                gatt.requestMtu(512);
            }else{
                setCharacteristicNotification(true);
            }*/
            discoverCount = 0;
        } else {

            // mGatt = null;
            Log.w("servieDiscovered", "onServicesDiscovered received: "
                    + status);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
        super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
        if (BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS == status) {
            setCharacteristicNotification(true);
        }else {
            gatt.requestMtu(153);
        }
    }
   
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic, gatt
                    .getDevice().getAddress());
        } else {

        }
    }

    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                  BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            //MyLog.i("onDescriptorWrite");
          //  NeedReconnect = true;
            isConnected=true;
        //    SharePreferenceUtils.setSpString(SharePreferenceUtils.KEY_ADDRESS,gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_onDescriptorWrite);
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: failed");
        }
    }

    ;

   
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {


        if (mGatt == null)
            return;
       Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged: " + ResolveData.byte2Hex(characteristic.getValue()));

        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic, gatt
                .getDevice().getAddress());
        //  SendData.sendBus(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic.getValue());
    }

    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            nextQueue();
        } else {
            //  MyLog.i("status" + status);
        }

    }

    ;

};


public boolean refreshDeviceCache(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    try {
        BluetoothGatt localBluetoothGatt = gatt;
        Method localMethod = localBluetoothGatt.getClass().getMethod(
                "refresh", new Class[0]);
        if (localMethod != null) {
            boolean bool = ((Boolean) localMethod.invoke(
                    localBluetoothGatt, new Object[0])).booleanValue();
            return bool;
        }
    } catch (Exception localException) {
        Log.e("s", "An exception occured while refreshing device");
    }
    return false;
}


private void broadcastUpdate(String action) {
    BleData bleData = new BleData();
    bleData.setAction(action);
    RxBus.getInstance().post(bleData);
    //Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    //sendBroadcast(intent);
}




private void broadcast update(String action,
                             BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String mac) {

 //   Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    BleData bleData = new BleData();
    bleData.setAction(action);
    bleData.setValue(data);
    RxBus.getInstance().post(bleData);

}

public void readValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    if (mGatt == null) return;
    mGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

}




public void writeValue(byte[] value) {
    if (mGatt == null||value==null) return;
    BluetoothGattService service = mGatt.getService(SERVICE_DATA);
    if (service == null) return;
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(DATA_Characteristic);
    if (characteristic == null) return;
    if (value[0] ==(byte) 0x47) {
        NeedReconnect = false;
    }
    characteristic.setValue(value);
    Log.i(TAG, "writeValue: "+ ResolveData.byte2Hex(value));
    mGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

}





public void setCharacteristicNotification(boolean enable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mGatt == null) return;
    BluetoothGattService service = mGatt.getService(SERVICE_DATA);
    if (service == null) return;
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(NOTIY_Characteristic);
    if (characteristic == null) return;
    mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enable);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic
            .getDescriptor(NOTIY);
    if (descriptor == null) {
        //MyLog.e("setCharacteristicNotification  descriptor=null，所以不能发送使能数据");
        return;
    }
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    if (mGatt == null)
        return;
    mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}





@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    //MyLog.i("servicer destory");
}


Queue<byte[]> queues=new LinkedList<>();

public void offerValue(byte[]value) {
    queues.offer(value);
}
public void nextQueue(){
    final Queue<byte[]> requests=queues;
    byte[]data=requests!=null?requests.poll():null;
    writeValue(data);
}
public boolean isConnected(){
    return this.isConnected;
}
```

}